# Find any one sequence of moves that can generate provided Connect-4 board state

Tags: algorithm, recursion, 2d-games

Given a valid [Connect-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four) board state in a matrix A(6x7), where

```
A[i][j] = '0',  if empty,
A[i][j] = 'r',  if filled with red stone,
A[i][j] = 'y',  if filled with yellow stone.
```

I am trying to think of an algorithm which can return any valid sequence of moves that can generate the given board state.

It can be assumed that red always starts the game.

Example:

```
A = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 y 0 0 0
     0 0 0 r 0 0 0
     0 0 0 y 0 0 0
     0 0 r r 0 0 0]

Valid sequence of moves:- 44443
```

44443 means ->
First player moves on column number 4,
then Second player moves on column number 4, ...
(Taking column numbers as 1-indexed)

**My approach**:-
-) First finding out the colour of last stone by parity of the number of non-empty positions. Let that colour be `last_coloured`.
-) Then take one topmost stone of colour `last_coloured` out from the board, recursively continue forward, if cannot find any stone of colour `last_coloured` then backtrack.

Although this approach can solve for 7*6 board in less than 16^21 steps.
(Edit: Thanks to @Prune for correcting this upper bound)

**Question 1)** Is there a better bound on the number of steps of the above approach?
**Question 2)** Is there any better approach?

Comment: What is the initial board state and how is the game being played?

Comment: I have added the wiki link for the game rules.

Comment: There is a missing detail: if the valid position is a winning position, then the four-in-a-row must be completed by the last move in the sequence, since it is not legal to keep playing after the game is over.

Comment: I'm confused -- how do you get 6^7 as your steps bound?  You have up to 7 choices for your first removal (assuming that the board is *not* filled).  Choosing a removal from `N` possibilities yields no more than `7-N+1` choices for the next move: the opponent's removal.

Comment: @Prune. Yeah, there was a mistake in my thought process. So, the upper bound can be 16^21. Right?

Comment: A little less than that, due to running out of stones at the end, but 16^21 a convenient expression.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this not as Connect-4, but a solitaire game on the same board.
Your goal is to remove all of the stones.  You have the rules for removing stones; now, it would improve the search tree if you had a good function to evaluate any board position.

Since you alternating color removals, you have

- rule: any removal must leave at least one stone of the other color exposed
- heuristic: maintain a balance between red and yellow stones exposed
- heuristic: if a column contains stones of only one color, then removing a stone from that column is the last resort.

This will also lead to a secondary term in your eval function: if your stone availability is out of balance, identify a column(s) where you need to reward digging to get to the scarce color.

For a board this small, I'm guessing that a relatively simple heuristic will provide a valid solution to any actual game position without backtracking: reasonable strategy by both players will promote a readily navigable mixture of stones.

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: But, consider a case where the last move was a winning move and the way of winning was 4 in a column, then the first stone removed should be from the column that contains all stones of the same colour.

Comment: Right: hence, the statement "You have the rules for removing stones".  That is one of the rules.